# How can I change hflex zk of Listbox

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, listbox, zk

I'm trying to change `hflex` inside listcell like that but `hflex` doesn't take by consideration.

```xml
<listcell>
    <listbox model="@load(each.taches)">
        <template name="model" var="item">
            <listitem visible="@load(not empty each.taches)">
                <listcell hflex="2">
                    <progressmeter style="span.z-progressmeter-image" value="@load(item.progres)" width="110px"
                                   height="16px">
                    </progressmeter>
                </listcell>
                <listcell hflex="min" style="text-align:center;">
                    <label width="45px" sclass="badge bg-primary" value="@load(c:cat(item.progres,'%'))"/>
                </listcell>
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your code before we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`hflex` attribute should be used in the list headers rather than in the cells:

```xml
<listcell>
    <listbox model="@load(each.taches)">
        <listhead>
            <listheader hflex="2"/>
            <listheader hflex="min"/>
        </listhead>
        <template name="model" var="item">
            <listitem visible="@load(not empty each.taches)">
                <listcell>
                    <progressmeter style="span.z-progressmeter-image" value="@load(item.progres)" width="110px"
                                   height="16px">
                    </progressmeter>
                </listcell>
                <listcell style="text-align:center;">
                    <label width="45px" sclass="badge bg-primary" value="@load(c:cat(item.progres,'%'))"/>
                </listcell>
```

Read more [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer's%20Reference/UI%20Patterns/Hflex%20and%20Vflex) and [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Grid%27s_Columns_and_Hflex)